# postMessage with SharePoint iframe resize not working correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, iframe

I have a problem trying to resize an iframe inside a SharePoint Online environment (O365) through Cross Domain. I've tried a bunch of solutions found on the net and nothing works except [Baker Humadi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558627/2171556) near the end about postMessage.

I added a Script Editor to the SharePoint page with the following (My iframe URL is of course pointing to my child page):

```
<script>
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    document.getElementById('frame').height = e.data + 'px';
},false);
</script>

<iframe id="frame" src="childpage" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

On the child page I've included the following (RestSection is being populated by some other means so please ignore content in this post):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var actual_height = document.getElementById('RestSection').scrollHeight;
    parent.postMessage(actual_height,"childpage"); 
    //* allows this to post to any parent iframe regardless of domain
}
</script>

<div id="RestSection">
    //List of things
</div>
```

When I am editing the code snippet in Sharepoint it is actually resizing the page as it should. When I Check In it stops working and I've noticed the height is set quite strange - perhaps some postMessage object?:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="childpage" scrolling="no" height="{"command":"RequestSuccess","requestIndex":1,"result":null}px"></iframe>
```

I don't understand why it works when I am editing the page in Sharepoint but suddenly does'nt when I check it In. Has anyone seen this behaviour before or could in some way enlighten me?

Comment: I should probably add that I sometimes see the resizing happen for a short time at the load of the page after Check In, but reverts back almost instantly after. I tried debugging with Firebug and could grab the page with the resizing working properly but only until after a new pageload. I tried setting an removeEventHandler so it would only fire once but had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking for a few things:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
        if(parseInt(e.data)){
            if (e.origin !== "childdomain")
            return;

            document.getElementById("frame").height = e.data + "px";
        } else {}
    }, false);
</script>
```

I have no clue why but the SharePoint probably had a bunch of events and therefore ended up with something like an object at the end. So I simply checked for an int (expected from childpage) and also kept it within the childdomain origin.